# How can I make the Outlook Calender be excessively "obnoxious" for certain reminder alerts?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, calendar, alert

When the Outlook Calendar has an alert, perhaps to tell me about a meeting or some other deadline, it sometimes does not appear as an alert box on the screen and instead appears as a blinking tab on the taskbar.

With the number of tabs I have open on the taskbar, it gets lost, and I probably am clicking too much to notice the alert box.  I've missed or become late for a few appointments due to this somewhat passive nature of the alert box.

Is there anything I can do to make the alert a modal window, or otherwise be more "obnoxious" so that I am assured I must deal with it and not potentially miss a meeting?  I would prefer to not have to use a different solution.

Comment: You could add a very, very long sound as the alarm?

Comment: @DaveRook - I'd love to, but I have to run silent.

Comment: @Madball73 - I could not find that on a basic search.  Good catch.  I prefer to close as duplicate rather than delete.

Comment: Very good catch @Madball73, I entered it in as a close vote.